# How to change a menu item background color in toolbar? -Android-

Tags: android

I'm working on Android. I have a menu item icon in my toolbar and, when I click on it, it displays a notification list. 
I want to change the icon's background color when the list is displayed. Just as eToro app does it:

[IMAGE: Icon hasn't been clicked and the background is the same as the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfYnc.jpg)

[IMAGE: Icon has been clicked and the background color has changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfaDs.jpg)

How do I achieve this?
My code:

```
//Here, I inflate the options in the activity's menu
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_management, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.notification_action);
        menuItem.setIcon(
            Converter.convertLayoutToImage(
                ManagementActivity.this,
                mNotificationCount,
                R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp
            )
        );
        return  true;
    }



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.notification_action:
         //Here,on the item click event, I want to change the item's background color, as Etoro does.

         //...

         //Then I trigger the action.. 
         openNotificationListFragment();
    }
    return  true;
}
```

Comment: could you provide us with all the relevant code (xml, notification activity, etc)

Comment: I don't think it would be possible if you're setting it as part of a menu resource, since you have no control beyond ensuring it displays as an icon instead of a list. However, if you insert a toolbar in the XML and are explicitly setting the icons in `ImageView`s or something similar, you could change the background color and maybe switch the icon if needed whenever it is clicked.